# Proving if an integral is positive, negative, or zero

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find $$\text{sgn}\left[\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-2014x^2}\sin(x) \, dx\right]$$
Source: TCU Calculus Bee 2014 (Held 8 months ago)
By logic because the $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\,dx=-\int_\pi^{2\pi} \sin(x)\,dx$ and the exponential is smaller in the interval $[\pi,2\pi]$, the area of the 2nd part is minimized, making it positive.

Can anyone provide a more rigorous proof of the answer?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you wanting to be more rigorous? The only part I can see that could be added is that the exponential term is decreasing since the derivative is negative, hence the integral in the latter interval is smaller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We divide the integral in the parts where $\sin x\geq 0$ and $\sin x\leq 0$,
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-2014x^2}\sin x\, dx
=
\int_0^{\pi}e^{-2014x^2}\sin x\, dx
+
\int_\pi^{2\pi}e^{-2014x^2}\sin x\, dx.
$$
In the second integral we do the change of variables $t=x-\pi$, to get
$$
\int_\pi^{2\pi}e^{-2014x^2}\sin x\, dx =
\int_0^{\pi}e^{-2014(t+\pi)^2}\sin (t+\pi)\, dt
$$
Since $\sin(t+\pi)=-\sin(t)$, we can write the integral as (we go back to the variable $x$ again)
$$
\int_0^\pi(e^{-2014x^2}-e^{-2014(x+\pi)^2})\sin x\, dx.
$$
Can you get the sign from here?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt, the answer is now updated with that detail.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the following is more rigorous, but is essentially the same answer:

We have

$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-2014x^2}\sin(x) \, dx
\\&=\int_0^{\pi} e^{-2014x^2}\sin(x)\,dx+\int_\pi^{2\pi} e^{-2014x^2}\sin(x)\,dx
\\&=\int_0^{\pi} e^{-2014x^2}\sin(x)\,dx-\int_\pi^{0} e^{-2014(2\pi-x)^2}\sin(2\pi-x)\,dx
\\&=\int_0^{\pi} e^{-2014x^2}\sin(x)\,dx+\int_0^{\pi} e^{-2014(2\pi-x)^2}\sin(2\pi-x)\,dx
\\&=\int_0^{\pi} e^{-2014x^2}\sin(x)\,dx-\int_0^{\pi} e^{-2014(2\pi-x)^2}\sin(x)\,dx
\\&=\int_0^{\pi} \left(e^{-2014x^2}-e^{-2014(2\pi-x)^2}\right)\sin(x)\,dx
\end{align}$

and since $2\pi-x> x$ on the interval $[0,\pi)$, we have $2014x^2<2014(2\pi-x)^2$  and so $e^{-2014x^2}> e^{-2014(2\pi-x)^2}$  for this interval, and finally since the value of sine is positive for this interval, we have

$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-2014x^2}\sin(x) \, dx=\int_0^{\pi} \left(e^{-2014x^2}-e^{-2014(2\pi-x)^2}\right)\sin(x)\,dx>0$$